# Generate signing certificate with start and end dates

Tags: c#, bash, powershell, openssl, asp.net-core-2.0

To create a self-signed certificate for token signing purposes (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686262/identityserver-client-authentication-with-public-private-keys-instead-of-shared)) I use `openssl`

```
    // ----------------
    // create crt + pfx files
    // ----------------

    // create key
    $ openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:x -out client.pass.key 2048
    $ openssl rsa -passin pass:x -in client.pass.key -out client.key

    // create certificate request (csr)
    $ openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr

    // create certificate (crt)
    $ openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in client.csr -signkey client.key -out client.crt

    // export pfx file from key and crt
    $ openssl pkcs12 -export -out client.pfx -inkey client.key -in client.crt

    // ----------------
    // create pem + pfx files
    // ----------------

    // create key + cert in pem format
    openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365

    // export pfx file from key and crt
    openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem
```

But `openssl` doesn't allow you to add the `NotBefore` and `NotAfter` fields of the certificate.

Is there another tools that lets you add those fields?

Comment: Why do you need `NotBefore`? Do you have a time machine?

Comment: lol.. good question... I'm using a .Net token validator (in `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens`) and I often get a validation failure around `... associated certificate is not yet valid. ValidFrom:., CurrentTime:...`. So in order to test the certificates I needed to set the  `NotBefore`. Another use case would be a certificate valid on a specific date in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Powershell command `New-SelfSignedCertificate` (available with PS 5.x) `-NotBefore` can be used to set the dates

```
    //---------------
    // create certificate
    //---------------

    // create certificate and add it to certificate store
    // couldn't find an option to export to a file without adding to the store
    New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type Custom -DnsName "www.example.com" -KeyUsage DigitalSignature -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -NotBefore "2018-04-11 00:00:00z"

    // list all certificates in the store and find the thumbprint of the created one
    PS C:\> Set-Location Cert:\LocalMachine\My
    PS Cert:\LocalMachine\My> Get-ChildItem | Format-Table Subject, FriendlyName, Thumbprint -AutoSize

    //---------------
    // export certificate
    //---------------

    // create password as a secure string
    $mypwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "1234" -Force -AsPlainText

    // export pfx file
    Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\xxxx | Export-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\client.pfx -Password $mypwd

    // export certificate
    // this will output as a binary file
    $cert = (Get-ChildItem -Path xxxx)
    Export-Certificate -Cert $cert -FilePath c:\user.cer -Type Cert

    // convert the binary file to base64 -- this is the format of the .cer file created by openssl
    $x = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([IO.File]::ReadAllBytes("c:/client.cer"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Can follow as explain [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31607/how-to-set-not-before-value-to-past-when-creating-certificate-request)

> As Thomas Pornin said, the certificate request does not contain any
>   dates, the notBefore and notAfter dates are set when the new
>   certificate is created (signed) by the CA.
>
> If you use the openssl ca tool, you can set them using `-startdate date`
>   and `-enddate date` command line options or using `default_startdate` and
>   `default_enddate` in `[ca]` section of the config file.

Comment: I'm using `openssl x509` and it doesn't allow `-startdate` (it accepts `-startdate` but does not use it)